# Find databases where a specific user is db_owner and db_datawriter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to create a query that lists all the database names where a specific user is allowed to read and write.

I was able to find how to list all the databases names but I don't know what to put to check the condition described above.

```
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
```

How do I check if a specific user is allowed to read and write in a database?

here is an exemple of what i want :

```
I have 3 database : First,Second and Third. my users are Alex and John. 
Alex is allowed to write and read in the First and Second database 
and John is allowed to write and read in the Second and the Third database.
What i want now, is to know in which databases Alex is allowed to write and read
and I need the name of the databases as result of the query
```

Comment: This [link](http://invalidlogic.com/2007/03/04/sql-server-tip-how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-database-through-t-sql/) might help. If it does, you can post it as an answer (after a certain amount of time has passed).

Answer (score 0):

this code will give you the ability to find the owner_sid and name of owner on all databases on the SQL Server

```
SELECT *, owner_sid,suser_sname(owner_sid) as 'owner'
FROM master.sys.databases
```

then get the owner_sid of the person you're interested in and then run with the where clause as the example here.

```
SELECT *, owner_sid,suser_sname(owner_sid) as 'owner'
FROM master.sys.databases
where owner_sid = 0x010500000000000515000000C34F142B1B2BCD5BE0276300E3B32200
```

The db_datawriter role gives implicit access to tables and views within a database so I'm not sure if you want to bring back databases that have table(s) that have the user in question as db_datawriter?

Comment: it's not really what i need i'll give you an exemple : i have 3 database : First,Second anTthird. my users are Alex and John. Alex is allowed to write and read in the First and Second database and John is allowed to write and read in the Second and the Third database. what i want now, is to know in which databases Alex is allowed to write and read and I need the name of the databases as result of the query